# Interpreting a difficult insurance clause

Tags: meaning-in-context, subordinate-clauses

I have an insurance clause which reads as follows:

> This policy only covers the Insured’s legal liability towards third parties, in cases where it has been proven that funds have been illegally withdrawn from a third party’s bank account by means of fraudulently obtaining such third party’s valid bank card details via an ATM which is owned, managed or controlled by ABC Ltd, up to the policy limits.

I don't understand when the policy comes into effect, because of the lack of punctuation (parentheses):

1. does it mean that THE FUNDS in question have to be obtained via the ATM referred to?
2. does it mean that THE BANK CARD DETAILS have to be obtained via the ATM referred to?
3. BOTH 1 and 2?

What is the grammatical explanation for this?

Comment: I think the lawyers (if it was lawyers) who wrote this did a terrible job. I believe it's ambiguous between (1) and (2) in standard English grammar. You need to know lawyer grammar—and for that you need a lawyer.

Comment: Where the funds were illegally withdrawn is unspecified. That the **bank card details** were obtained via the ATM "owned, managed, etc." is specified. Therefore, only what is given by your 2. I'm not sure that grammar alone is going to answer your question; logic is key and semantics are the ticket.

Comment: I agree with Peter Shor, it is entirely ambiguous. This is how civil lawyers make a lot of their money - by having long arguments in court about ambiguous phraseology.

Comment: It's called jargon and within the community is probably is VERY specific.  Latin used to be used to encapsulate legal prose.

Answer (score 2):

The grammar question is whether "via an ATM" modifies "withdrawn" or "obtaining" or both.  Now, of course, lawyers can and have been known to argue anything before a court, but from a syntactic view, the "via" phrase is a little too far from "withdrawn" to specify its manner.  There are two other clues.  The first is that people don't generally say they got $20 via an ATM; they say they got $20 *from* an ATM.

The second is semantic.  The ATMs in question are restricted to those that belong in some way to ABC Ltd.  Presumably, ABC Ltd. warrants that their ATMs are fraud-resistant and that their employees who handle ATM operations are trustworthy.  For other bank companies, not so much.  So it's a fair inference that the insurance kicks in for any breach of ATM security on the part of ABC Ltd.

But grammar, idiom, and common sense only take you so far.  Call up the insurance provider and ask, "If someone hacks an ATM belonging to ABC and uses the information to steal money from my account using an ATM belonging to XYZ, am I covered?"

That will get you closer.